# new content type permission

Tags: nodes, users

I created a content type called: **Spreed Sheets**. Then in */admin/people/permissions* I make sure I checked these 3 permissions for authenticated users :

> Spreed Sheets: Create new content
>
> Spreed Sheets: Edit own content
>
> Spreed Sheets: Delete own content

then I loged in with an authenticated user (not admin) and I only have access to *node/add/spreedsheets* but when I'm login with admin and want to add another content type such as article from *admin/content/add content* it always redirect me to *node/add/spreedsheets* !!what should i do to give back the full permission to admin?

Comment: try node/add/article

Comment: I tried it, it opens the article form , but I don't see the content type list any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create content-type (not content) then this is link `admin/structure/types` where all content types are listed (in drupal7). But If you are talking about create content then you can add content `node/add` here all types will be listed.

Comment: I know the difference between creating a content type and a content. I already create my custom content type which calls spreddsheets. the problem is something else. please read the question one more time

Comment: "I'm login with admin and want to add another content type such as article from admin/content/add". As I understand form this, you want to add another custom content type. So the url "admin/content/add" is wrong for this operation. and as tell above on monymirza's comment, you can add article. and you can access node/add/spreedsheets, So you have permission to add content. So which content type list you are talking about ? list to add new **content** or list to add **content-type** ?

Comment: I already created a custom content type from **admin/structure/content type** which names **spreedsheets**. the problem is that when I go to **admin/content** and click on the **add content** link , when you click on this link, in a default installation of drupal you see a list which show "Article" it always redirect me to **node/add/spreedsheets**, it doesn't show the list of all content types to select one of them. I should change the URL manually.

Comment: then may be you don't have menus enabled under "add content" for other content types on admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation. I think you have only spreedsheets enabled under "ad content"

Comment: I will check it right now, tanx a lot

Comment: Tanx a lot! everything works fine now! tanx a lot

Comment: You can mark answer as correct, If this helps :)

Comment: It will help me to unlock some features, like:- commenting on questions.

Comment: I checked the answer as correct :)